# Using tf.get_variable(...) with an unknown batch size

Tags: tensorflow

Given that I have some input batch `x` with shape `(batch_size, n_features)` how would I use `tf.get_variable(...)` to create another matrix with shape `(batch_size)` if it isn't known ahead of time.

For example I am able to do:

`b = tf.zeros(shape = (tf.shape(x)[0]))`

But I am unable to do:

`b = tf.get_variable("b", shape = (tf.shape(x)[0]), initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.0))`

Comment: You have a typo right there, after `shape=` there should be a parenthesis opening, in both code snippets

Comment: oops fixed it!!

Comment: How does batch size affects one of your Variable ? It is common that they donnot interact.

Comment: When you need to create the hidden state for an RNN don't you need to know how many samples are in the batch?

Comment: if the problem is solved due to a simple typo, just remove the question

Comment: It's not solved :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.Variable(dims=[tf.shape(x)[0]], validate_shape=False)` to set a dynamic shape for batch size.